# How can I convert the following raw query to Sequelize ORM?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am unable to convert the following query to the Sequilize ORM format, Is there any online tool that can do this?

```
SELECT * FROM sms where created_at in (SELECT max(created_at) FROM sms GROUP BY contact_id ) order by created_at desc
```

Comment: use a sequelize raw querry, dont think it is good idea to try use models for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

const latestSms = await Sms.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'message', 'created_at', 'contact_id'],
  where: {
    created_at: {
      [Op.in]: sequelize.literal(`(
        SELECT max(created_at)
        FROM sms
        GROUP BY contact_id
      )`)
    }
  },
  order: [['created_at', 'DESC']]
});
```